# Quasipoisson or negative binomial glmm with differing dispersion by group

Tags: r, count-data, glmm, overdispersion

I have a set of count data, which look something like this:

```
    Count   Count.type   Site
    299     A            A   
    325     A            A       
    192     A            A       
    180     B            A       
    304     B            A       
    332     B            A       
    2919    A            B       
    2014    A            B       
    2220    A            B       
    1967    B            B       
    1799    B            B       
    2001    B            B
```

... and so on. There are only two levels of Count.type, and about ten Sites.

I'd like to fit a model similar to:

```
glmmPQL(Count ~ Count.type, random = ~ 1 | Site, family="poisson")
```

My problem is that the dispersion of counts is dramatically higher for one level of Count.type than for the other. I have tried to find a negative binomial or quasipoisson approach, but in the examples I can find (e.g., here [How does glm.nb work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27773/how-does-glm-nb-work)), a single theta is estimated and used on all groups.

Does anyone know of a solution that would estimate (or allow me to manually specify) different dispersion parameters for the two groups in Count.type, that is robust for count data?

Comment: In what sense does the dispersion differ by group? The variance is supposed to vary by mean? How did you determine that the dispersion varies problematically?

Comment: Variance differs by Count.type very clearly (in the residuals of the glmmPQL model, the sd is about an order of magnitude greater for type B than type A, and that contrast is highly significant on a Levene's test). Variance correlates with mean for Count.type B, but not (so far as I can tell) for Count.type A. I'm not sure if there is a formal test for this being 'likely to be problematic', but the difference in variance is huge and the sample sizes are fairly small, so I can't imagine it *not* being a problem.

Comment: I would look into what is possible with gamlss

Comment: If you are open to doing Bayesian analysis, you can use [brms](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/) to fit a negative binomial regression in which the dispersion parameter is a function of group. Here is a similar question where I show how to do it: [Poisson or Negative Binomial regression when within-cluster data follow different distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/625131/237901).